# Are realistic hypothetical situation based questions permitted?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

The question would have to be very specific and answerable, but would hypothetical (and realistic) questions be permitted?

What I mean by this is, would situations that do not necessarily happen to the person asking the question, but could happen (and may have happened) be permitted?

Comment: As long as you're able to provide any specific details if requested, I don't see any problem.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset thank you, I would base any hypotheticals on events that I have heard of occurring in passing (i.e. not privy to the exact details) and would be possible to occur again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**I don't see any reason why they should not be permitted, and judged by the same measure as all questions.** If they are a good fit for the site (which probably requires that they be realistic), they add value and should be allowed!

---

Moreover, I don't think you can prevent them efficiently. There's no way you can tell, when I ask a question, whether it's really happened to me. Sometimes, I ask what I think are good questions [from my past experiences](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7200/2700) (in that particular case, I added a PS, but I don't always). Sometimes, I make up questions… (based on real-life circumstances that have happened, or could have happened to others)

For example, if you look at my questions, you may realize that I am:

- [an undergrad student](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13137/2700)
- [a post-doc](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/8800/2700)
- [a research group leader](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/12372/2700)
- [editor of a journal](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11926/2700)
- [a senior researcher who chairs session in prestigious conferences](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11854/2700)
- and my name is [John Smith](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/12235/2700)

I can tell you (in confidence): not all of these are true!

Comment: You're _not_ John Smith?  But thank you for your point there, that a hypothetical should not be obviously a hypothetical.

Answer (score 2):

**No, they are really not a good fit to the site at all.**

The reason is, that however good your imagination is, there may be crucial details that would relate to a real-life situation, that you just haven't anticipated.

That makes the answers much less useful to anyone with a real-world problem that looks broadly like what you made up.

The Help Cente  explicitly states that you must **Try to extract the fundamental question from the specific problem at hand.**

If you don't have that specific problem, don't ask about it. Fake questions are as bad as fake answers, and the site is better off without them.

The [tour](https://academia.stackexchange.com/about), that all new users of the site are directed to, is very explicit about this, and it's a principle that applies across all Stack Exchange sites:

> Focus on questions about an **actual problem** you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

(emphasis as in the original)

Comment: I'm not sure what you refer to as “fake answers”, but using the Q&A format, within its limit, to share knowledge (e.g. by self-answering) [is, and has long been, allowed and even encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz) on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Regarding the main point of your answer, @UV-D specifically stated “realistic” and “very specific and answerable” questions, i.e. they concern a real-world problem, even though it may not have occurred to you (or occurred yet, or occurred in this particular alternative universe :)